# How to DeserializeObject a string with a curly braces in the value?

Tags: c#, json, xunit

I have this string which I need to deserialize.

`"{\"errors\":{\"validationError\":[\"Custom error message here.\"]},\"title\":\"One or more validation errors occurred.\",\"status\":400}"`

This is my code and I am using XUnit for my testing.

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("api/ABC/Check?draftId=" + draftId);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerificationResponseError>(responseString);
Assert.Equal("Custom error message here.", result.validationError[0]);
```

and this is my `VerificationResponseError` class.

```
public class VerificationResponseError {
    public string errors { get; set; }
    public List<string> validationError { get; set; }
}
```

But, it breaks at

`var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerificationResponseError>(responseString);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have an incorrect class, shouldn't it be something like this instead?

```
public class Errors
{
    public List<string> validationError { get; set; }
}

public class VerificationResponseError
{
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}
```

You can use this tool to verify that https://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your class does not represent your json structure. Try next:

```
public class VerificationResponseError
{
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}

public class Errors
{
    public List<string> validationError { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerificationResponseError>(responseString);
```